# NAO robot not returning recognized words - getdata is empty

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to make NAO understand the words in the vocabulary and return the same when read from its memory. Below is the code. But somehow the getdata() from memory object returns empty.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
from naoqi import ALProxy

import time
data=[]

asr = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition", ip, 9559)

asr.pause(True)
asr.setLanguage("English")


vocabulary = ["yes", "no", "please","water usage","Thanks"]


asr.setVocabulary(vocabulary, False)
asr.subscribe(ip)
memProxy = ALProxy("ALMemory", ip, 9559)
memProxy.subscribeToEvent('WordRecognized',ip,'wordRecognized')

time.sleep(10)

asr.unsubscribe(ip)
data=memProxy.getData("WordRecognized")
print( "data: %s" % data )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you stopped the asr with asr.pause(True).
You only need to write this asr.pause(False) just before your time.sleep.

```
from naoqi import ALProxy

import time

data=[]
ip = "your_robot_ip.local"
asr = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition", ip, 9559)

asr.pause(True)
asr.setLanguage("English")


vocabulary = ["yes", "no", "please","water usage","Thanks"]


asr.setVocabulary(vocabulary, False)
asr.subscribe(ip)
memProxy = ALProxy("ALMemory", ip, 9559)
memProxy.subscribeToEvent('WordRecognized',ip,'wordRecognized')

asr.pause(False)

time.sleep(10)

asr.unsubscribe(ip)
data=memProxy.getData("WordRecognized")
print( "data: %s" % data )
```

You can also use standard boxes in choregraphe.